# Unable to read internal storage/SD card on Samsung Grand Prime Plus

Tags: samsung, sd-card, storage

I follow a tutorial for setting my SD card as part of *Internal storage* with *adb*. Here is a photo of how it looks like:

[image: IMG:]

As you can see, I have 7.88 GB used out of 37.47 GB and my device tells me I don't have enough space (the capacity of cellphone storage is 8 GB), so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the configuration or something.

Can someone help me?

- Cellphone: Samsung Grand Prime Plus
- Model number: SM-G532M
- Android version: 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the SD card
2. Remove apps
3. Reinstall the card as adopted storage
4. Then reinstall the apps while adopted storage is on
5. That will make the physical space of your phone stay empty and disable the notifications about low memory